How to retrive one field from list of objects and collect into another list
I want to fetch all the ids from a list and add them to another list to pass to further query.
I am having a BigQuery , where output is List . From this list I need to retrieve the ids and add to new list so that I can use it further.
Tried the following:
Example bqList from BQ:
[{id: 10, name: 'abc', count: 1},{id:13,name:'dmd', count: 3}]

expected output:
List<String> itemList = [10, 13]

Tried the following:
List<String> itemList = (List<String>) bqList.stream()
                     .filter(entity -> entity.getId()!=null)
                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ItemData::getId));

I am using Java 8 , Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

.groupingBy returns a Map which you are trying to typecase to List which is not feasible.
It returns a Map with keys as argument passed which in your case is ItemData::getId and values as List<ItemData>.
So in order to get a list of keys and not the map of objects grouped based on keys, you could try something like this:
List itemList= new ArrayList(bqList.stream()
                     .filter(entity -> entity.getId()!=null)
                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ItemData::getId))
                     .keySet());


bqliSt is a list of objects, this object had id , name fields. I want to retrieve only the id filed values from this list and add to nw list

you can use to get list of ids- List<Integer> newList =list.stream().map(entity->entity.getId()).peek(e-> System.out.println(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
